# Occasionally receiving 403 error on Prestashop (both frontend and admin)

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, http-status-code-403

So I have this problem regarding Prestashop.

I created a subdomain for an website because I wanted to upgrade from 1.4.x to 1.6.x and I wanted the original website up and running.

I made a back-up and everything, I upgraded from 1.4.x to 1.6.x, installed a new theme, made some css / jquery changes and tested it and everything was working great.

Now the problems started to appear after moving the website from the subdomain to the domain (eg: from dev.websitename.com to websitename.com). Now I occasionally receive 403 errors for basically everything (from a jquery file, to the whole page). After a few ctrl + f5's everything works fine (but I cannot keep telling a customer to hit ctrl + f5 until the website works :| )

I tried everything I could think of. I checked and double checked the permissions on files / directories (since that's what 403 is basically telling me) and I cannot find the problem.

My hair is starting to fall because of how much inconvenience this is.

Can someone help me? Or at least point me to the right direction?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

So for anyone that is interested, the solution was to increase the number of requests per page and then everything worked! Hope it helped anyone interested.

Have a good day!